# How to read javascript variable using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm learning to read `javascript` variable using `Selenium WebDriver` (latest version). Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Below is my try on *whoscored.com* and it keeps showing error

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{               
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/81/Tournaments/3/Germany-Bundesliga");
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    var tournament = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("tournament-fixture-wrapper")));             
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;                
    var obj = (object)js.ExecuteScript("return window.allRegions;"); //always return error 'Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.    
}
```

Comment: And, what is the JavaScript you want read? Can you provide that?

Comment: it's in the link http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/81/Tournaments/3/Germany-Bundesliga var allRegions = [{type:1, id:248, flg:'flg-caf', name: 'Africa', tournaments: [{id:290, url:'/Regions/248/Tournaments/290/Africa-CAF-Champions-League', name:'CAF Champions League'},{id:573, url:'/Regions/248/Tournaments/573/Africa-', name:''},... sorry it's too long to paste here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change

```
var obj = (object)js.ExecuteScript("return window.allRegions;");
```

to

```
List<object> list = js.ExecuteScript("return window.allRegions;") as List<object>;
```

since, `return window.allRegions;` does not return a `string` but `array` of `objects`.

**Edit**

Just went through the page and looks like `window.allRegions` returns a `List` of `json` objects. And, does feel like creating a list of json object can be unwanted overwhelming of programming. I suggest you to narrow down the goal either with modifying the `javascript` or performing some filtering like following.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var tournament = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("tournament-fixture-wrapper")));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

//getting count of regions
long count = (long)js.ExecuteScript("return window.allRegions.length;");

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    //grab the name of countries if that's what you wanted
    string name = js.ExecuteScript("return window.allRegions[" + i + "].name;") as string;

    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

> **Print:**
>
> Africa
>   Albania
>   Algeria
>   ...
>   Zambia
>   Zimbabwe

Comment: OK. But, what are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: thanks for your help. sry, i fell asleep last night :)

Comment: @namvo that's ok hope this helped